# a weird Pickle glitch

Tags: python, pickle

this is the code that gets the error:

```
month_date = pickle.load(open("month.dat", "rb"))
```

this is the error I get:

```
File "/Users/lvanrem/PythonTest/weatherAI_V2.py", line 25, in <module>
month_date = pickle.load(open("month.dat", "rb"))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

let me know if you can help me...

Comment: The file is empty

Comment: Or at least not complete. The `EOFError` is telling you that `pickle.load` needed to read more data to completely decode what it had already read, but there was no more data to read from the file. So the question is, what *is* in `month.dat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the awnser was indeed that the file was empty.
my solution was that i added an except statement that would fill the file with a backupfile.
this happened when i interupted my python script.

thx for the awnser (=